# passing values from tiles2 definition to jsp file in struts2

Tags: struts2, tiles2

I am using tiles 2 with struts2.
My tiles definition look like this:-

```
        <definition name="store-tiles" extends="baseLayout">    
           <put-attribute name="title" value="test"  />
           <put-attribute name="menulink" value="support" type="string" />
           <put-attribute name="slider" value="/empty.jsp" />
           <put-attribute name="products" value="/products.jsp" />
        </definition>
```

I want to use title or menulink variale  in products.jsp as jsp variable

```
           <tiles:useAttribute name="menulink"/>
           <c:out value="${menulink}"/>
```

It throws exceptions that expression is not allowed in c:out.
I have seen the same thing working fine with Struts 1.x and tiles 1.x version.
whats the issue with Struts2/tiles2 ?

Please give me a workaround.

Comment: What version of JSP/JSTL are you using? Can you post the exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this could do it:

```
<tiles:importAttribute name="title"/>
<tiles:importAttribute name="menuLink"/>
<s:property value="#attr['title']"/>
<s:property value="#attr['menuLink']"/>
```